# Pipe and getchar()

Tags: c, pipe

Confusion about how getchar() interacts with stdin when being piped from an empty file.

Here's the simple c code test_program.c

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main( ) {

   int c;

   printf( "Enter a value :");
   c = getchar( );

   printf( "\nYou entered: ");
   putchar( c );
   printf( "\n");

   printf( "Enter a value :");
   c = getchar( );

   printf( "\nYou entered: ");
   putchar( c );
   printf( "\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Curious what would happen when I pipe an empty file (a) to stdin...

```
$ cat a | ./test_program
Enter a value :
You entered: �
Enter a value :
You entered: �
```

I guess I would have expected test_program to block till I actually feed it data. Why does it read from stdin where the file a is empty and why does it print garbage as well?

Comment: You'll need to test for end-of-file: if (c == EOF) die();

Comment: I see the EOF (-1) is what is being read each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet explains it pretty well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) 
{
    int c = getchar( );
    if(c == EOF) 
        printf("EOF\n");
}
```

> I guess I would have expected test_program to block till I actually feed it data. Why does it read from stdin where the file a is empty and why does it print garbage as well?

When you (try to) read data from an empty stream, you will get an EOF. That's how you know that the stream is empty.

Comment: Yep... it prints -1 as an int (EOF). Thanks for the sanity check!